# XeLaTex XeSyriac not getting fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, syriac

I am attempting to input Syriac into XeLaTeX but is not loading correctly.
I am using MiKTeX on windows below is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xesyriac}
\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

But when I attempt to build the file, I receive an undefined control sequence error concerning a package internal command, which brings me to the line marked by an arrow in **xesyriac.sty**

```
    \notbool{xsy@nodefaultfonts}{%
\setmainsyriacfont{Estrangelo Edessa}
\newsyriacfont\estrfont{Estrangelo Edessa}
\newsyriacfont\sertofont{Serto Jerusalem}
\newsyriacfont\madnhafont{East Syriac Adiabene}}{%

->   \AtBeginDocument{\ifdef{\syriacfont}{}{\PackageError{XeSyriac}{A main Syriac font is not defined}{Use \protect\setsyriacfont\space in the preamble to define a main Syriac font.}}}}
```

I posted the lines above because they seem relevant, I have all three fonts installed on my windows machine, but it seems XeLaTeX cannot find them.

Answer (score 2):

To save others time, `xesyriac` comes from [users.ox.ac.uk/~wolf2305/xesyriac.html](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~wolf2305/xesyriac.html), and the fonts referred to in the question are available at [www.bethmardutho.org/index.php/resources/fonts.html](http://www.bethmardutho.org/index.php/resources/fonts.html). The package requires `xecolour`, so download that from CTAN, because TeX Live has `xecolor`, not `xecolour`.

Now you will probably get this error:

```
ERROR: fontspec error: "font-not-found"

--- TeX said ---
!
! The font "Aramaic Numbers" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.243 ...ace\ArmNum[FakeBold=1.3]{Aramaic Numbers}

kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `Aramaic Numbers', contains ' '

l.243 ...ace\ArmNum[FakeBold=1.3]{Aramaic Numbers}
```

Googling for a font called “Aramaic Numbers” led nowhere.

However, I was able to compile a document by editing `xesyriac.sty`, changing line 243 from “\newfontface\ArmNum[FakeBold=1.3]{Aramaic Numbers}” to “\newfontface\ArmNum{Estrangelo Edessa}”.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[insyriac=true,loadfonts,numerals=alphabetic]{xesyriac}
\begin{document}
\huge
ܐܣܛܪܢܓܠܐ
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I was able to use the western, eastern, and alphabetic options for numerals, but not the aramaic option.

It looks like time to contact the author of `xesyriac`. Meanwhile, if you edit the package for your own purposes, it’s best to rename it (e.g., call it `mysyriac.sty`, and make line 42 read, “\ProvidesPackage{mysyriac}%”).